# Reset counter cache on all data of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am looking for a beautiful way to update a counter cache of a given model.

Here are my model:

```
class GameParticipation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game, counter_cache: true
end
```

And:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :game_participations
end
```

Isn't it something better than iterating on each element like the following code ?

```
Game.ids.each {|id| Game.reset_counters(id, :game_participations) }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To update all the counter cache in one request I found inspiration on http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2016/02/05/proper-counter-cache-migrations-in-rails/

It can be done in one request with SQL :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL.squish
    UPDATE games
    SET game_participations_count = (SELECT count(1)
                               FROM game_participations
                              WHERE game_participations.game_id = games.id)
SQL
```

It takes much less time to execute since all the updating is done in one request.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use `each`, but other than that, i think the answer is no, there is no built in method to update multiple counters. if that is what you mean by "beautiful"?

Comment: Full active record request => not having to iterate through all element with map/each (with is not effective regarding performances)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gem 'counter_culture' could solve your problem.
https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture

```rb
Product.counter_culture_fix_counts
# will automatically fix counts for all counter caches defined on Product
```

Comment: This is an entirely different way to do counters so wouldn't solve the users issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty `rake` task. Add the association names to the array and run it:

```
# /lib/tasks/counter_caches.rake

namespace :counter_caches do
  # ==========================================================================================================
  # Resets all counter caches
  # Usage:
  #  $ rake counter_caches:reset_all
  # ==========================================================================================================
    desc 'Resets all counter caches.'
    task reset_all: :environment do
      # Add each association with a `counter` column to the array
      game_associations = [:game_participations]

      # Update in batches
      Game.includes(game_associations).in_batches(of: 1000, load: true).each_record do |record|
        Game.reset_counters(record.id, *game_associations)
      end
    end
end
```

Also, do yourself a favor and make sure you default the counter column to `0` (instead of `null`) when you create the migration:

```
add_column :games, :game_participations_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false
```